# Passport authenticate responding with HTTP 500 and does not call route methods after authentication succeeds

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

This is what my router method looks like.

```
router.get("/getData",
  passport.authenticate("consumer-validation"),
  getAccountData
);
```

I have a basic strategy defined here from [passport-custom](https://github.com/mbell8903/passport-custom)

```
  const consumerValidationStrategy = new Strategy((req, done) => {
    return done(null, { name: "John Doe" })
  });
  
  passport.use("consumer-validation", consumerValidationStrategy);
```

When I hit my `/getData` endpoint, I expect to see `getAccountData` being called but that doesn't happen.

I have also confirmed that the strategy is working by returning `done("Error")` which results in a 401 instead of 500.

Comment: 500 responses are usually caused by coding errors, so check the logs of your Express server.

Comment: It's a been awhile for me, but shouldn't the first param in the call to `router.get()` be a string type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

I needed to add serialization.

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this line exactly how you have it in your code: `router.get(/getData,` If so then I think it's missing quotation marks around the path value: `router.get("/getData",`.

Currently, you most probably have a syntax error because of the `/` used in the path.

Comment: Oops, forgot to put that in the question. Updated!